# Why does a datetimeoffset have 28 hours of timezones?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetimeoffset

I am looking into using the datetimeoffset for SQL Server 2008. According to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) there is a time zone offset range of -14:00 through +14:00. I can understand going 12 hours from UTC in each direction, one hour per timezone. I think I understand 13 hours in each direction, for daylight savings time. I just dont get 14 hours?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Living next to a time-zone border that involved a 20+ hour jump would be very difficult, so political entities near the International Date Line simply define their timezone as extending beyond +/-12 for the convenience of the people living there.

This forces the effective "data flip line" to have a very funny shape but to never affect "neighbors" for a fairly expansive definition of "neighbor". It is only possible because of how sparely populated the Pacific Ocean is.

This is basically the same reason that time-zone boundaries tend to avoid big cities and follow either political boundaries or major geographical features such as big rivers, mountain chains or deserts.

Answer (score 5):

Christmas Islands are +14:00, see [here.](http://www.worldtimezone.com/time/wtzresult.php?CiID=42216)

Answer (score 2):

Some places have a timezone offset larger than 12. I can only recall Tonga (+13), but there might be more.

Edit: ah, Line Islands, +14:00 :)

[Timezone map on Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Timezones2008.png)